# 'Set Text' action on a web-element intermittently generates TYPE_021 error

Tags: automationanywhere

I intermittently run into a TYPE_021 error when I perform a 'Set Text' action on a web-element that would be used as a drop-down in a manual flow, but simply inputting a value is legal.

I chose a 'Set Text' versus a Click command followed by a Keystrokes command because 'Set Text' seems more stable. Also, I did not attempt the obvious flow of selecting from the dropdown because the necessary value is not available in the dropdown.

What would cause a TYPE_021 error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the availability of user guides for Automation Anywhere.. which is frustrating. I'm also not familiar with those type of errors but I would suggest the following methods:

1. Enclose Set Text command with Error Handling so that the whole task would not fail if the drop-down value is not available, then have If/Else commands after to check if it is valid or not.

Error Handling (Action: Continue; Task Status: Pass; Variable Operation = "True")

2. Move the drop-down selection part at the latter part of the task. Maybe the page was not fully loaded yet which causes failure.
3. Use Click command to select the value. Click the drop-down button then click the value. Modify the properties to insert the value required, maybe on HTML Value or HTML InnerText. You may enclose it with Error Handling if needed.

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your reply.

Comment: I have implemented enclosing the command in Error Handling, and it helps some. I've considered running the command in a loop until it doesn't fail, but that is a lot trickier than it sounds. The eh for potential dialog boxes is a nightmare. One simple Set Text becomes 112 lines of walking on egg shells. Unfortunately the drop-down selection is a trigger for populating other drop-down values later on in the task, so the order cannot be changed. Lastly, in this case, the value I'm inputting is not in the drop-down at all, so I'm forced to use Set Text. Editting the above comment timed out (lol).